What is the best approaching to creating an embedding layer of a combination of two categorical variables?
I have two integer encoded categorical variables, one indexed from 0 and another indexed  from 1. What is the best way of embedding unique tuples (Category A, Category B), taking into account that additional categories may be added in the future? The possible combinations are sparse, so for the most part each member in Category A maps to one member in Category B with a few exceptions. Should I just create an embedding for each and concatenate them together or is there a better approach?
